# Why is my neural network handwritten digital test set cross entropy correct, the output rate is always 10% correct compared to the label?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

I run my code in `spyder`,the test set cross entropy is correct, but the accuracy of test set is always very low. This is my code. I use the mnist. Any advice how I can improve the performance?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])
test_x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
test_y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/xuenzhu/mnist_data", one_hot=True)

hidden1 = fully_connected(x,100,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1,100,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

outputs = fully_connected(hidden2,10,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=outputs)
reduce_mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

equal_result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputs,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
cast_result = tf.cast(equal_result,dtype=tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(cast_result)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(reduce_mean_loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
    for i in range(10000):
        xs,ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={x:xs,y:ys})
        if i%1000==0:
                print(sess.run(equal_result,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
                print(sess.run(reduce_mean_loss,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))[enter image description here][1]
                print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: "the test set cross entropy is correct" what do you mean by that? How do you know it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no use in using a ReLu activation function before applying `softmax_cross_entropy`. Change the activation function in the last fully connected layer to `None` and you'll get good accuracy.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])
test_x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,784])
test_y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/xuenzhu/mnist_data", one_hot=True)

hidden1 = fully_connected(x,100,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

hidden2 = fully_connected(hidden1,100,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())

outputs = fully_connected(hidden2,10,activation_fn=None,weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())







loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=outputs)
reduce_mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)

equal_result = tf.equal(tf.argmax(outputs,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
cast_result = tf.cast(equal_result,dtype=tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(cast_result)

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(reduce_mean_loss)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
    for i in range(10000):
        xs,ys = mnist.train.next_batch(128)
        sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={x:xs,y:ys})
        if i%1000==0:
                print(sess.run(equal_result,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
                print(sess.run(reduce_mean_loss,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
                print(sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images,y:mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: thank you very much.I took your suggestion,and the accuracy become 95%.but i don't know why changing relu to none in the last layer has such a good result.Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Happy to help. ReLu sets some of its inputs to zero. That's fine in a hidden layer, but in the output layer, you want to retain what was passed forward by the previous layers.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing this

> for i in range(10000): #Try increasing this value to >10k. Try 100k or higher

You should be able to see an increase in accuracy thereafter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't think this is it. I tried running the OP's code with `for i in range(100000)`, but accuracy never went past .5.

Comment: Update: @marco_gorelli
I tried changing the activation function of the (outputs) layer to `activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid`. I managed to reach an accuracy of 90+% with the exact same code from OP.